# How do nested struct values work with @Observable when re-rendering ui?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have following observable made to keep track of a custom modal state

```
import SwiftUI


@Observable class ModalObservable {
  // State
  var view = ModalViewType.Profile
  var open = false
  
  // Actions
  func show(view: ModalViewType) {
    self.open = true
    self.view = view
  }
  
  func hide() {
    self.open = false
  }
}
```

Instead of having each state value as a separate variable, I want to make a `var state = ModalState()` one, where `ModalState` will be a struct containing each individual value.

I'm unable to find any docs on how this could affect ui re-rendering logic, mainly will my ui re-render when anything in this struct changes or only when nested value that my ui is accessing changes?

As example, if my ui only uses `ModalObservable.state.open` will it re-render when `view` changes?

Comment: You would have to test it but I think Apple mentioned in the WWDC video that Observable was much more targeted than the ObservableObject invalidation approach. So it should be much more targeted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's be clear about what "re-render" means. If you mean "creates an entirely new view", then this will only happen if the *identity* of the view changes. If your view's identity does not depend on `ModalObservable`, then how you change `ModelObservable` is not relevant. This can be experimentally detected by `onAppear`.

If you mean "updates an existing view", then this depends on the view's *dependencies*. SwiftUI creates a dependency graph from your views and the states/bindings/environments etc that the views use, and updates the view if any of the dependencies change. This can be experimentally detected by having `body` produce a side effect (though `body` is also called when the view is first created).

Here is some code that you can use to experiment:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var model = ModalObservable()
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print("ContentView updates")
        UpdateDetector(observable: model)
        Button("Change Open") {
            model.changeOpen()
        }
        Button("Change View") {
            model.changeView()
        }
    }
}

struct UpdateDetector: View {
    let observable: ModalObservable
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print("UpdateDetector updates")
        Text(observable.state.open ? "Open" : "Close")
    }
}

@Observable class ModalObservable {
  var state = ModelState()
  func changeView() {
    self.state.view = UUID().uuidString
  }
  
  func changeOpen() {
    self.state.open.toggle()
  }
}

struct ModelState {    
    var view = "Foo"
    var open = false
}
```

Here SwiftUI has determined that `UpdateDetector` depends on `observable.state`, so it updates whenever it observes a change in `observable.state`, i.e. when either of the buttons is pressed. On the other hand, `ContentView` does not update, because it does not depend on any observable property.

Note that `observable.state.open` and `observable.state.view` does not count as two separate observable properties, because the `@Observable` macro only adds `@ObservationTracked` to `state`.

Here's another example, this time with `Binding`s.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var model = ModalObservable()
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print("ContentView updates")
        UpdateDetector(open: $model.state.open)
        Button("Change Open") {
            model.changeOpen()
        }
        Button("Change View") {
            model.changeView()
        }
    }
}

struct UpdateDetector: View {
    @Binding var open: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print("UpdateDetector updates")
        Text(open ? "Open" : "Close")
    }
}
```

Here, `UpdateDetector` only depends on the `open` binding, so pressing "Change View" does not update it, but "Change Open" does. On the other hand, `ContentView` now also depends on the `open` binding, since a binding is two-way. Pressing "Change Open" updates `ContentView` too.

---

If you *do* want `observable.state.open` and `observable.state.view` to be tracked separately, you can change `ModelState` to also be an `@Observable` class, though this also changes semantics.

```
@Observable
class ModelState {
    var view = "Foo"
    var open = false
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you use `@Observable` modifier it's almost the same as you inerhit from `ObservableObject`

Difference is:

```
@Observable                                                 | ObservableObject
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Observable class MyModel { }                               | class MyModel: ObservableObject { }

No need to use @Published at all                            | Need to use @Published on each var that must be cause of refresh view

In View: @State var model                                   | In View: @StateObject var model; @ObservedObject var model

Change of public var (struct) will re-render view           | Only if @Published
                          (same in case of change of property of struct var)

Change of private var (struct) will NOT re-render view      | Will NOT re-render view

Change of private(set) var (struct) will re-render view     | Only if @Published

Change of public var (class) will NOT re-render view        | Will NOT re-render view even if it is @Published
                          (same in case of change of property of class var)
```

> To perform refresh in case of property of your model is class you need to use '@Observable' modifier on this class or inerhit class from `ObservableObject`
>
> AND(!!!!!) assign it to extra view's var like here:

```
struct SomeView : View {
    @ObservedObject var model : SomeViewModel
    @ObservedObject var someClassValue: MyClass
    
    init(model: SomeViewModel) {
        self.model = model
    
        //as this is class we must do it observable and assign into view manually
        self.someClassValue = model.someClassValue
    }

    var body: some View {
         //here we can use model.someStructValue directly

         // or we can use local someClassValue taken from VIEW, BUT NOT value from model

    }

}

class SomeViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var someStructValue: Bool = false
    var someClassValue: MyClass = MyClass() //myClass : ObservableObject

}
```

---

Usage of `@Observable` modifier make code more "clean", but it is causes some extra view refreshes in some cases that you can skip in case of usage inerhitance from `ObservableObject`. Ofc you can use in some cases `@Observable` in some cases `ObservableObject`, but it will create different codestyle in single project.

My opinion: SwiftUI is not lightweight UI system, so better do not use `@Observable` as it makes it even slower because of extra refreshes.

My choice is to use ObservableObject